# Pymongo Convert Query Result to Customized Type

Tags: python, mongodb

I created a class like `A`

```
class A(object):
    self.field1=...
    self.field2=...
```

Then I insert the an object into mongo by pymongo APIs:

```
...
collection.insert_one(A.__dict__)
```

Then I find the object by:

```
a=collection.find({...})
```

But `type(a)` is `dict`, how to convert `a` to type `A`?

Comment: pymongo will only return raw dict types.. you might have to use `a=A.from_dict(collection.find({...}))` where `from_dict` is a static method inside class A returns object of type A from dict

Comment: Do you mean that I need to define a static method inside A?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pattern I like:

```
import pymongo
from bson import ObjectId
from typing import Optional
db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']

class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.field1: Optional[str] = None
        self.field2: Optional[str] = None

    def load(self, record: dict) -> None:
        self.field1 = record['field1']
        self.field2 = record['field2']

    def find_one(self, filter) -> None:
        record = db.a.find_one(filter)
        self.load(record)

    def save(self) -> ObjectId:
        return db.a.insert(self.to_dict())

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        return { 'field1': self.field1,
                 'field2': self.field2 }

a1 = A()
a1.field1 = 'B'
a1.field2 = 'C'
a1.save()
a2 = A()
a2.find_one(filter={'field1': 'B'})
a2.field2 = 'D'
a2.save()
for record in db.a.find({}, {'_id': 0}):
    print (record)
```

gives:

```
{'field1': 'B', 'field2': 'C'}
{'field1': 'B', 'field2': 'D'}
```

Comment: This looks good. But what if the fields inside the object are not simple types, like another class object which is imported from somewhere else.

Comment: Then just define the relevant types within the class. If you give me an example I can provide some ideas.